# Ajax call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to get value in JavaScript using Ajax Call, 
I am using the following code:

```
<script>
    var value = $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"get_result.php",
        data:"{'abc':" + $abc + "}",
    });

    alert(value);
</script>
```

while I wrote following code in `get_reult.php`:

```
<?php
    echo $abc= "Working";
?>
```

Happy to know about good solution

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery tutorial to learn how to make Ajax calls with jQuery and process the response with the server: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. The purpose of this tutorial is to help developers in exactly your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'get_result.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'abc='+$abc,
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    //console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `success` parameter in your call:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"get_result.php",
    data:"{'abc':" + $abc + "}",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
</script>
```

Read more about `AJAX` calls with `jQuery`[here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is asynchronous so that the result is probably not available when you call `alert(value);`

You will need to put this code into a success block.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"get_result.php",
    data:"{'abc':" + $abc + "}"
}).success (function(value) 
{
  alert(value);
});
```